# conditions that an annihilator banach algebra will be a dual banach algebra

Tags: banach-algebras, algebras

a banach algebra $\frak{A}$ is called an annihilator algebra if, for arbitrary closed left ideal $\frak{L}$ and closed right adeal $\frak{R}$ in $\frak{A}$, both of the following conditions are satisfied:

$(1):\mathcal{A}_l(\frak{L})=\{0\}$ if and only if ${\frak{L}}=\frak{A}$.

$(2):\mathcal{A}_r(\frak{R})=\{0\}$ if and only if ${\frak{R}}=\frak{A}$.

and $\frak{A}$ is a dual algebra if

$(1):\mathcal{A}_l[\mathcal{A}_r(\frak{L})]=\frak{L}$

$(2):\mathcal{A}_r[\mathcal{A}_l(\frak{R})]=\frak{R}$

where for arbitrary set $E\subseteq A$, we have

$\mathcal{A}_l(E)=\{x\in A\;|\;xE=\{0\}\}$

$\mathcal{A}_r(E)=\{x\in A\;|\;Ex=\{0\}\}$

then $\mathcal{A}_l(E)$ is called left annihilator and $\mathcal{A}_r(E)$ the right annihilator of $E$.

it is easily proved that an annihilator algebra is dual and even if $\frak{A}$ be a semisimple annihilator banach algebra, then it is not necessary that $\frak{A}$ be a dual algebra. now my question is that

> under what conditions an annihilator banach algebra will be a dual algebra?